# How to make TableCell editable , so it automatically updates the data class?

Tags: javafx, edit, tablecell

I am making a system for a school project , and one part of it is a `TableView` that is populated with rows using my own data class `InventoryData` that has properties correspondent to the table columns. I would like to make cells in some columns editable using a `TextField`, so that when an edit is committed, it will update the `InventoryData` object's relevant property.

I tried setting `TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn()` as the cell factory of the columns. Although, now after committing the edit, the text in the cell will change, I don't think it is changing the property in the `InventoryData` object. The reason why I think that, is because when I try to edit that cell again ( after already being edited once), the `TextField` shows the former value ( before the first edit).

Did I do something wrong , or is that normal behavior and I have to implement the commits myself?

Here's the code for `InventoryData` :

```
package UILayer.TableData;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import ModelLayer.Product;

public class InventoryData {


    // From Product
    private Product productObj;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty id;
    private SimpleStringProperty name;

    // Constructor - converts Product obj into InventoryData
    public InventoryData(Product product) 
    {
        this.productObj = product;

        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(product.getId());
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(product.getName())

    }


    // GET & SET
    public Product getProduct() 
    {
        return productObj;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id.get();
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
        productObj.setName(name);
        System.out.println(productObj.getName());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need your `InventoryData` class to use the [JavaFX Properties pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107). Specifically it needs property-type accessor methods in order to retrieve the property in the table cells. Without this, the cell value factory just calls the standard `getName()` or `getId()` method, and wraps the result in a `ReadOnlyStringWrapper` (or `ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper`): the table cell cannot change the values of those wrappers (since they are read only).

```
public class InventoryData {


    // From Product
    private Product productObj;
    private IntegerProperty id;
    private StringProperty name;

    // Constructor - converts Product obj into InventoryData
    public InventoryData(Product product) 
    {
        this.productObj = product;

        this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(product.getId());
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(product.getName())

        this.name.addListener((obs, oldName, newName) -> 
            productObj.setName(newName));

    }


    // GET & SET
    public Product getProduct() 
    {
        return productObj;
    }

    public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
        return id ;
    }
    public final int getId() {
        return idProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setId(int id) {
        idProperty().set(id);
    }

    public StringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name ;
    }
    public final String getName() {
        return nameProperty().get();
    }
    public final void setName(String name) {
        this.nameProperty().set(name);
        // productObj.setName(name);
        // System.out.println(productObj.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: I didn't think of that thank you , it seems to work. Can you please specify what is then called when the table cell gets committed ? Cause it would be nice if it could also get the `productObj.setName(name)` done in the process, if it is possible ofc.

**EDIT:** I didn't notice the listener in the constructor at all -.-

Comment: It calls `nameProperty().set(...)`, so the listener should keep `product.name` in sync...

Comment: Yes , as I've said, my eyes kinda skipped the listener lines :) Thank you for your help ! Have a nice day